# SEO влияние иконок на правильность работы сайта?

Tags: seo, icon, fontawesome

Как лучше отображать иконки с точки зрения оптимизации и SEO? Я видел и отображение каждой иконки в отдельном div и вставку их в button и в тег  (как у fontawesome) и добавление их через псевдоклассы :before :after (если они реализованы через шрифты), Браузеры роботы вообще, когда читают сайт осознают что пользователь иконкой, как бы намекает что будет делать-тот или иной блок (опять же на примере fontawesome)?

Answer (score 1):

нет, поисковые роботы определять изображенное на иконах пока не научились
(руки нейронных сетей не дошли). зато им можно и нужно помочь, добавляя на ссылки аттрибут title и на img аттрибут alt с текстом.

например:

```
<a href="/blog/create" class="fa fa-blog" title="Создать новый блог"></a>
<a href="/blog/create"><img src="/img/create_blog.png" alt="Создать новый блог"/></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете иконки как изображения, то для поисковой оптимизации создавайте семантическое содержание в атрибуте alt каждого изображения. Например, если линк связан с видео, то примените содержание для alt, что-то связанное с видео "иконка видео камеры для урл видео", или что-то подобное. При установке иконок вы можете применять любые правила css. Это впрямую не касается поисковой оптимизации, но косвенно это влияет на юзабилити - удобство просмотра. Я рекомендую вам применять иконки как ***[мнемонические символы HTML](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B2_HTML)*** - ***[список W3](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_dingbats.asp)*** (в левом меню вы можете выбирать группу символов, в секторе HTML Symbols) + ***[список с поиском](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/)***. Также вы можете применять ***[иконки как буквы Гугл](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web)*** - ***[инфо W3](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/)***.